# Pushdown filter for Cassandra in Spark Cassanda Connector for SQL sub query - Custom Catalyst Rule?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Spark Cassandra Connector using Spark Thrift server to enable SQL query on Cassandra database. Most of the SQL query works on Cassandra Partition Key with PushBack filter except SQL sub query. If I hit this query as below, I don't see Push down filter to Cassandra.

Sample `SQL SELECT` query with `IN` clause is as below:

```
SELECT * from playlists where playerId=1 and song_id in (select songId from songlists and release_date=cast('2018-06-12' as date));
```

When I run this SQL query on Spark Thrift server it shows no Push back filter in the log as below -

---

### C * Filter: []

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE playlists (
  playerId int,
  song_id int,
  title text,
  album text,
  artist text,
  release_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY  ((playerId, song_id),release_date));

CREATE TABLE songlists (
  songId int,
  release_date date
  PRIMARY KEY  (songId,release_date));
```

Wanted to check if there is any way to push this filter to Cassandra in Spark Cassandra Connector.  Does this  require a custom catalyst rule? Where can I find any sample rule for such use cases?

Comment: I believe that Russel already answered this question on the Google Groups...

Comment: Yeah, I saw his reply, I am looking for integration point tips if this is possible via catalyst rule? Do we have any such catalyst rule available for Cassandra for custom SQL query? Usually Catalyst is for changing the logical plan for better optimization in Spark but here I am seeing that no preliminary push back filter going to Cassandra.